# CKEditor "Source" button does not brings back the full html

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I have written a full html code

```
<div style="background-color:red">&nbsp;</div>
```

But when I edit the content and click on the "Source" button provided in the CKEditor toolbar. nothing is showing up

In Advanced content filter I have given in Extra allowed content

```
p(*)[*]{*};div(*)[*]{*};li(*)[*]{*};ul(*)[*]{*}
```

In Custom JavaScript configuration I have given

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know D8's CKEditor doesn't allow you to use the `style` attribute to prevent click jacking attacks, [example](https://javascript.info/clickjacking).

Can't remember if D7 CKeditor did or not, but either way, it's bad security practice to allow people to use `style` attribute.

The better approach is to use a class.

```
<div class="bg-red">...something goes here...</div>
```

Your Drupal theme's **style.css**

```
.bg-red { 
  background-color:red;
}
```